# Авторизация через facebook

Tags: oauth, авторизация, facebook

Доброго времени суток! Сделал на сайте авторизацию по протоколу OAuth. Все работает, но имя пользователя отдается транслитом (Ivan Taranov). Можно ли получать его на русском? Может, кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы через Graph API получаете его, добавьте параметр `locale`:

```
/v2.1/me?fields=id,name&locale=ru_RU
```